# How to get search strings from global search?

Tags: lightning-experience, einstein-analytics, analytics, event-monitoring

Is there any way in Salesforce to get what the users are searching in Salesforce?

I want to extract search terms from standard global search as well.

PS: External tools such as SPLUNK, and Google Analytics can also work, but to my best knowledge we aren't able to capture the search terms directly.

Answer (score 5):

The only way I am aware, for the standard global search, is via Event Monitoring. Sadly it has an [additional cost](https://www.salesforce.com/editions-pricing/platform/shield/).

I only had very brief access to Event Monitoring, but when I did I downloaded offline what I could. One of the log types is for "Search" and "SearchClick". The "Search" log contains a column called "SEARCH_QUERY" which definitely shows the search term.

There are [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_search.htm) for the supported event types, but the description for the Search event log is:

> Search events contain details about the user’s search query. All
> searches within the app, including Experience Cloud sites, are
> included. However, unauthenticated users won’t have a unique
> Salesforce user ID.